# How do I convert .md to .html USING Hugo WITHOUT 3rd party themes?

Tags: html, markdown, hugo

When running `hugo -D` I could see the `.xml` files getting generated by default.
Any configuration changes needed or how can I get the very simple `.HTML` file converted from `.MD` file

Comment: Hey Saidu, can you give a bit more info? Hugo natively DOES turn markdown into HTML files. That's what it does... So I'm assuming you may have something in your config maybe a bit off, specifically in "Output Types"

Answer (score 1):

You can disable XML generation in the config file.